# api test with postman in angular project

Tags: postman

I want to test my api for resister which is post type it contain username, email, password, phone number. I really don't know how to test api in postman. It should be authorization type of no-auth. After this I have to validate or test api for login then it generate some key then I have to use this key to test other api's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i believe to test post api withpostman
first you need to put the route of your api and the type of http in your case POST
then go to header tab and add this header(under key/value):-
Content-Type :application/json
then under body tab select row option and insert valid json as below
{
    "username": "Omar Shabro",
    "email": "o4@o.com",
    "phone": "0599"

}
```

Comment: Sorry this message- Could not get any response

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?
can you test the api from your code is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

depends first find if any form of auth is being used in such case you will need to handled the auth before sending requests. check the link bellow it will help you in case of auth

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers